# Deploy MEAN stack application

Tags: node.js, angular, express, vue.js

So, I have developed a web app (enterprise level) using Vue as front end, Node as backend and MongoDB for database. During development phase, we used separated servers to host Vuejs app and Nodejs app.

This doesn't sounds right at production level. My question is, **what is the best way (most preferred way) to host a MEAN stack app on a single server (frontend being either Vue or Angular).** I have read a lot about serving "dist" folder using express server. But is it a workaround or is it a legit solution?

Also, should I consider using docker or kubernetes?
App engine and elb are out of scope as they don't have MongoDB support and Atlas it very costly.

Comment: There are places where you can deploy you mean stack app. Is you server and front end in different projects or everything is in one? (post picture of folders)

Answer (score 0):

I've recently written a post about [deploying the frontend](https://jonathanmh.com/deploying-a-vue-js-single-page-app-including-router-with-docker/).

You can easily use two docker containers that test and build, but you can also just install node.js on a server. Mongodb could be an easy dependency with docker or any Linux vps. Do you have Linux experience?

Docker file recipe:

```
# Create the container from the alpine linux image
FROM alpine:3.7

# Add nginx and nodejs
RUN apk add --update nginx nodejs

# Create the directories we will need
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/nginx/vue-single-page-app
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/nginx
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html

# Copy the respective nginx configuration files
COPY nginx_config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY nginx_config/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Set the directory we want to run the next commands for
WORKDIR /tmp/nginx/vue-single-page-app
# Copy our source code into the container
COPY . .
# Install the dependencies, can be commented out if you're running the same node version
RUN npm install

# run webpack and the vue-loader
RUN npm run build

# copy the built app to our served directory
RUN cp -r dist/* /var/www/html

# make all files belong to the nginx user
RUN chown nginx:nginx /var/www/html

# start nginx and keep the process from backgrounding and the container from quitting
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```